# understanding (and modelling) grocery shopping lists

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema

I am having a hard time understanding how multiple product orders are mapped out.

What is the best way of modelling a shopping list for multiple customers?

I am developing an C# application that mocks the system we use at work for processing customer grocery orders. After a fair amount of schema research, I am looking at something very simple, like this:

```
Products {
ProductID,
Name,
Price
}

Customers {
CustomerID,
FirstName,
SecondName
}

Customer_Orders {
OrderID
CustomerID
ProductID
Quantity
}
```

This does make sense to me, but what seems weird is the Customer_Orders table. As I understand, if a customer places an order with 10 different items, I'll have 10 rows, with the same OrderID and CustomerID yet different ProductIDs, representing the shopping list.

This seems counter-intuitive to me, I imagine ProductID should be made up of a collection of values (how I'd program it) and not separate rows.

Is my thinking way off here, or am I supposed to model it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Order should be **Primary Key** which you can *link* to another table where order details will be given.

```
Products {
ProductID,
Name,
Price
}

Customers {
CustomerID,
FirstName,
SecondName
}

Customer_Orders {
OrderID (Primary Key)
CustomerID
...
}

Order_details {
OrderID
ProductID
Quantity
}
```

Comment: so Order_details will be populated with say, 50 items with the same OrderID for example? Or 50 entries with 40 different products and 10 apples? etc..

Comment: Right! you would want to research more on **one to many and many to many relationships**.

Comment: I was just under the impression that it would lead to a lot of records, very very quickly.

Comment: @JimmyStewart This is what a database is meant to do: store a lot of data. Raw number of rows is pretty irrelevant for most intents and purposes, at least compared to amount of overall data as well as query/design complexity.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - thanks, that's good to know. I'll not be using a lot of data as it's just for educational purposes, still I like to know.